# What kind of cypher do Ubuntu uses on its full disk encryption?

Tags: encryption

One important thing that make me install 13.04 instead of the stable 12.04 LTS is the encryption of the installation. I want to achieve the same in Windows 7 with TrueCrypt.

I want to know what kind of encryption do Ubuntu uses for the disk encryption utility that comes with 13.04+ (AES, Serpent, etc... / Hash) and so I would like to know if only the installation filesystem is protected or the swap is also cyphered (whole disk).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses AES-CDC by default.